# jQuery UI Autocomplete - how to reset user-visible text?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a simple jQuery UI Autocomplete box.  Works fine.  Since I have a series of them, I want to have a global Reset button that will null out all the various select and input boxes.  How do I access the user-visible text (as well as the underlying value) of the Autocomplete box in order to null out values?

I've tried various options including:

```
$('#autocompleteSearchBox').val('Test1');
$('#autocompleteSearchBox').parent().find('label').text('Test2');
$('#autocompleteSearchBox').next().val('Test3');
$('input.ui-autocomplete-input').val('Test4');
```

None of these affect the user-visible text.  Any ideas?

Edit - jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ypFXP/).

Comment: will you plz show your code on http://jsfiddle.net/ ..so that its easy for us to fix it ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.ui-autocomplete-input').val('');
```

I've updated your fiddle to show this - http://jsfiddle.net/ypFXP/4/.

If you're looking for the underlying source you can get at that via:

```
$('#autocompleteSearch').autocomplete('option', 'source');
```

Comment: First bit of code works for the user-viewable area.  Not sure how I would use the second bit to handle the underlying value of the autocomplete box.  Using the second bit only changes the source of the data, it doesn't affect the current value of the box itself.

Comment: Still would like to know the answer to my comment, but I found a way to build around it.  Thanks for the help on the first bit.